# Adding a NOT NULL Column to an Existing Table in Laravel SQLite

Tags: laravel, sqlite

I'm trying to add a foreign key to an existing table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('employee', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid("agency_id");
    }
}
```

and SQLite is throwing error:

> General error: 1 Cannot add a NOT NULL column with default value NULL (SQL: alter table "employees" add column "agency_id" varchar not null)

I cannot add a default value of an empty string as the type is UUID. What can I do?

Comment: If you made it not null you should have some sort of value to insert otherwise make it nullable.

Answer (score 0):

`SQLite` would typically choose NULL, but you've specified it can't be NULL, so what should it be? It has no way of knowing.

When adding a table from scratch, you can specify `NOT NULL`. However, you can't do this when adding a column. `SQLite`'s specification says you have to have a default for this.
You could specify the default value, such as  :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('employee', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid("agency_id")->nullable();
    }
}
```

Comment: 0 isn't a uuid though? It will fail there.

Comment: Whats about `$table->uuid("agency_id")->nullable();`?

Comment: But it's a required field for our data structure. Allowing nullable is not a fix.

Comment: @f7n If you don't want the column to be `nullable` - then you need to let Laravel know what the default should be. Like : `default('');`